# Change content of div depending on user input?

Tags: php, html, mysql, dynamic

I have created a table of people within my database using the following code:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "database";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT clientname, clientsurname, address1, postcode, dob FROM clients";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<table class='table table-bordered'><tr><th>Name</th>     <th>Surname</th><th>Address</th><th>Postcode</th><th>Date of Birth</th><th>Select Client</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["clientname"]."</td><td>".$row["clientsurname"]."</td><td>".$row["address1"]."</td><td>".$row["postcode"]."</td><td>".$row["dob"]. "</td><td class='btn btn-block btn-info btn-flat'><a href=\"edit_form.php?id=$row[clientname]\" style='color:#fff;'>Select</a></td></tr>";
                            }
    echo "</table>";
    } else {
    echo "There are 0 clients in the system matching your search criteria";
   }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

I want to know if it is possible that when a user clicks the Select Client button if that clients full data can populate a div to the side of the table?

If this is possible how would I do this?

Comment: Use ajax for display and change data in DIV.

Comment: There is two ways first is you load your client detail on page load in a div and onclick just show it and other is onclick send AJAX request to that particular id and fetch record and add a div to HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the .fadeToggle or .fadeTo in jquery to make it appear on the side of the screen. This can be used many different ways but for the most part this is what it looks like.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('h2').fadeTo('fast',1);
    });
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaHurlburt/x5f3bz37/

Comment: oh, when I click another client the information doesnt change? do I need to apply some sort of clear function?

Comment: you should just make multiple versions of the code and fill in the client info. replace the 'h2' with the id or class names of the client info you want to appear. You will have to position the new client info with css but it should work good after that.